# Minhogim of Breslau, Poland

Tags: minhag, ashkenazi, geography

As a descendant of a long line of Jews from [Breslau, Poland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wroc%C5%82aw), I was wondering:
Are there any specific minhogim of Breslau (modern day [Wrocław](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wroc%C5%82aw)) and if yes what are they?

This might be different from Litvaks and Minhogei Polin in general due to its close proximity to Eretz Ashkenaz on the western edge of Poland and its influence from Hamburg and Frankfurt.

(Please provide sources.)

By the way, Breslau is not the same place as [Breslov or Bratslav](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bratslav) in Ukraine (the home of the famous [R. Nachman of Breslov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nachman_of_Breslov)).

Comment: http://www.shamash.org/lists/scj-faq/HTML/faq/02-10.html This Breslov er website mentions Breslau is not Breslov. (For reference)

Comment: @JoshuaPearl - I have edited it a little. Maybe you might add why you think the minhogim might be different than the Litvaks?

Comment: @EzraHoerster Is this what you meant?

Comment: I would assume them to be Yekkes (as it was traditionally German) and not Poilish/Litvish.

Comment: @ShmuelBrin Generally speaking, kehillos north of the River Elbe practices Minhagei Polin, whereas kehillos south of the River Elbe practiced Minhagei Ashkenaz. However, this does not apply to every individual kehilloh, it is only general. I don't know if Breslau was Polin or Ashkenaz or a mixture of the two.

Comment: Joshua, Berlin and Hamburg, which are farther west, both practice (the old) Minhog Polin.

Comment: @JoshuaPearl - B''H yes the question is now perfect!

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt I, of course, know that! However, my fellow yekke, they were very much influenced by the Ashkenazim of the further west!